# Application virtual path of web config. Getting settings form web.config in test unit project. MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, settings

I have problem with getting settings from web.config in my test project. I have static method in my DAL project:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration oConfigurationManager = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath);
```

Method works fine in main MVC project (I get `"\"` from `ApplicationVirtualPath`, and oConfigurationManager uses web.config from the project.). In test project I get following path:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
```

Because:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath
```

is null.

My question is: what is ApplicationVirtualPath and why do I get it null instead of the real one.

Comment: What edition of visual studio do you use?

Comment: VS 2015 Community version 14.0.25431.01